# Missing every swing element in java in netbeans, project correpted

Tags: user-interface, awt

I don't know why this class shows errors in every line. This was fine but suddenly i close and open my netbeans IDE and it shows every-line error.
I tried to figure out where the problem is, but i can't. I notice that **every button,table,label** are missing, otherwise variable, database connection is ok.
My imports are:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import Main.SqlConnection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;
import Main.Check;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
```

Errors look like [this image](http://imgur.com/a/AWV76) .
How do i solve this ? 
Do i need to recover my project ?

Comment: Did you changed JDK version, or Libraries related to JDK?

Comment: can you show full code of the java file. Sometimes it happens when you adding wrong codes.

Comment: @ChannaJayamuni How can i recover it ? Just restore my backup ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kBES6EWa Here is my full code

Comment: Problem solved :) , Just recover my project

Answer (score 1):

add `try{` block just before following line

```
 private void btn_SaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your solution as follows**

Consider following method. It don't contain a `try` keyword. add try keyword there. Then it will be fixed.

```
private void btn_SaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try { //this line is not present in your code. add this
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        if (value_for_show_table == 61) {
            stringBuffer.append("insert into class6a where ");
        } else if (value_for_show_table == 62) {
            stringBuffer.append("insert into class6b where ");
        } else if (value_for_show_table == 71) {
            stringBuffer.append("insert into class7a where ");
        } else if (value_for_show_table == 72) {
            stringBuffer.append("insert into class7b where ");
        } else if (value_for_show_table == 81) {
            stringBuffer.append("insert into class8a where ");
        } else if (value_for_show_table == 82) {
            stringBuffer.append("insert into class8b  ");
        }
        stringBuffer.append("where '" + txt_Username.getText() + "','" + txt_roll.getText() + "','" + txt_Bangla1st.getText() + "',"
                + "'" + txt_Bangla2nd.getText() + "','" + txt_English1st.getText() + "','" + txt_English2nd.getText() + "',"
                + "'" + txt_Math.getText() + "','" + txt_Social.getText() + "','" + txt_Religion.getText() + "',");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Roll number can't be duplicate");
    }
}
```

Additionally It may happen according to many reasons. There are one of them.

- When project cannot find the JDK location or when missing core library of java
- When using a reserved word as a parameter or class name